# What is correct way to do CRUD operation in JPQL when working with multiple IDs

Tags: java, jpa, orm, persistence, crud

I was wondering what is the pereferred/correct way to do operations that involve fetching and removing multiple entity objects?

Here's an example:

Here's the way that uses IN operator:

```
@Override
public void delete(Iterable<Long> ids) {
    startTransaction();

    Query query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(Entity.DELETE_ALL_BY_IDS_NQ);
    query.setParameter(Entity.DELETE_ALL_BY_IDS_PARAMS[0], ids);
    query.executeUpdate();

    endTransaction();
    closeTransaction();
}
```

where the named query looks like this:

```
@NamedQuery(
        name = "Entity.deleteAllByIds",
        query = "DELETE from Entity e WHERE e.id IN :ids"
)
```

And here is the way that just does it via `EntityManager#remove`

```
public void delete(Iterable<Long> ids) {
    int count = 0;

    startTransaction();

    for (Long id : ids) {
        count++;

        Query query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(ImeiTacEntity.IMEITAC_READ_BY_ID_NQ);
        query.setParameter(ImeiTacEntity.IMEITAC_READ_BY_ID_PARAMS[0], id);

        ImeiTacEntity entity = (ImeiTacEntity) query.getSingleResult();
        getEntityManager().remove(entity);

        if ((count % BATCH_THRESHOLD) == 0) {
            endTransaction();
            clearTransaction();
            startTransaction();
        }
    }

    endTransaction();
    closeTransaction();
}
```

and the read query is this:

```
@NamedQuery(
    name = "Entity.readById", 
    query = "SELECT e from Entity e WHERE e.id = :id"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first operation is an example of a JPQL 'bulk' operation and while more efficient in terms of number of SQL statements executed, you should be aware of the following important points:

https://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_bulk_ops

> **10.2.9. JPQL Bulk Update and Delete**
>
> Operations Bulk update and delete operations apply to entities of a
>   single entity class (together with its subclasses, if any).
>
> A delete operation only applies to entities of the specified class and
>   its subclasses. **It does not cascade to related entities**. The
>   new_value specified for an update operation must be compatible in type
>   with the state-field to which it is assigned. **Bulk update maps
>   directly to a database update operation, bypassing optimistic locking
>   checks**. Portable applications must manually update the value of the
>   version column, if desired, and/or manually validate the value of the
>   version column. **The persistence context is not synchronized with the
>   result of the bulk update or delete**. Caution should be used when
>   executing bulk update or delete operations because **they may result
>   in inconsistencies between the database and the entities in the active
>   persistence context**. In general, bulk update and delete operations
>   should only be performed within a separate transaction or at the
>   beginning of a transaction (before entities have been accessed whose
>   state might be affected by such operations).

Therefore, when deciding on one or other approach you will need to take the above into account.

Answer (score 1):

First option definitely has its advantages in this case. The biggest one being that it translates to single `delete` SQL query, while in the second option you load each entity before passing it to `em.remove()`.